# Move files from one location to another in Linux using Symbolic link

Tags: linux, ubuntu, move, symlink

I would like to know is it possible through symbolic (soft) link to move files from one location (A) to another (B) when files are getting created in the A location.

Comment: you can use SCP command [https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye]

Comment: I have a program which creates files in some location, which is a default location (on which i dont have control). Since i dont have sufficient disk space in that location i want it to be moved to a new location, with the symbolic link created in the default location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have some program creating files in some directory (e.g. in `/fixed/location/`), and you want the data to be elsewhere (e.g `/data/dir/somefile.txt`...)

If you know *in advance* the name of the created files, you could make them symbolic links before starting the program:

```
 ln -s /data/dir/somefile.txt /fixed/location/file.txt
```

and if you create that symbolic link before running the program, it will write the data into `/data/dir/somefile.txt` even if that file does not exist (but the directory `/data/dir` should exist when you type that `ln -s`)

Another (Linux specific) possibility is to make a bind mount. If e.g. you want the data inside `/usr/src/` to reside in `/home/Src/` you could first `mkdir /home/Src` then  e.g. add the following line in your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
 /usr/src              /home/Src                 none    bind    0 0
```

I'm actually doing that (on `/usr/src` and `/usr/local`) for every Linux system where `/home/`  is a different filesystem, because I want them to be in the same backed up file system as `/home/`